# Integrating Quick books items data using QBFC

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online, qbfc

I am importing  Quick books item data from quick books to CSV file using QBFC.

I have seen few fields have same value(103).

1. ParentRefType = 103
2. SalesTaxCodeRefType = 103
3. ExpenseAccountType = 103
4. PrefVendorType = 103
5. PurchaseTaxCodeType = 103

[Find the file here](https://skydrive.live.com/#cid=5E1D2EB753C00953&id=5E1D2EB753C00953!114)

Let me know why ? I does not see this values directly form Quick book application.

I hope this values coming from background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that 103 refers to the FullName Reference Type. And yes, these values are coming from the "background" of Quickbooks and QBFC so you will likely not see them anywhere in the Quickbooks UI.

All of the fields you listed above are Reference Types of a Quickbooks object (i.e. Parent, SalesTaxCode, ExpenseAccount, etc). You can reference an object through two means: a ListID or a FullName. The Type of the reference indicates whether or not the object is using a ListID reference or a FullName reference.

The integer 103 appears to be the internal identifier for a FullName reference type. Notice in your export file ([Item.csv](https://skydrive.live.com/#cid=5E1D2EB753C00953&id=5E1D2EB753C00953!114)) that all of the reference objects use the FullName type to reference objects (see the columns ParentRefFullName, SalesTaxCodeRefFullName, ExpenseAccountRefFullName, etc). Notice also that the columns immediately after these are the Ref Type columns (i.e. ParentRefType, SalesTaxCodeRefType, etc). These Ref Type columns are set to 103 whenever the cell to the left (the FullName cell) contains a value. When there is no FullName reference, the Type column contains a zero (which I'm assuming means Ref Type Not Known or something similar).

The [QBFC Quick Reference](https://member.developer.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/qbsdk/staticHtml/QBFC-QuickRef.html) states the following (under the [IQBBaseRef](https://member.developer.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/qbsdk/staticHtml/QBFC-QuickRef.html#IQBBaseRef) definition):

> IQBBaseRef is used for all qbXML "object references," which refer to objects. For example, an
>   AccountRef refers to an account in the chart of accounts. If a request specifies both ListID
>   and FullName, QuickBooks will use only the ListID.

That last sentence is important to note. A ListID reference takes priority over a FullName reference. It appears though that there are no ListID references used in your export file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.If 103 refers to the FullName Reference Type.

Comment: In export file IncomeAccountType has diff values like 109 ,309,566. even IncomeAccountFullName has diff names.Let me know why this field only has diff vales.

Comment: The data in the IncomeAccountType column does not make sense. For example, The value "Construction Income:Materials Income" in the IncomeAccountFullName column corresponds to the IncomeAccountType value of 103, 309 and 566. Is it possible that this data has been corrupted? How is the CSV file being exported? Is it possible that there is a bug in that code? It's interesting that the IncomeAccountType column values are identical to the Type column for rows 46 through 60.

Comment: Technically, the IncomeAccountType and some of the other columns should include the Ref designation (i.e. IncomeAccountRefType) since they are RefTypes and not just Types. See the ItemQuery Response Message in the [Onscreen Reference for Intuit SDKs](https://member.developer.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html). Keeping this in mind makes it all the more unusual that the RefType is something other than 103 when there is in fact an obvious value in the associated FullName column.